# Optimize spark join on different keys for same data frame

Tags: apache-spark

I have been working on case where a dataframe is joined with more than one data frame separately, on different cols, that too frequently.
I was wondering how to optimize the join to make them faster.
We can consider the dataset to be big in size so broadcast joins is not an option.

For eg:

```
> schema_df1  = new StructType() .add(StructField("key1", StringType,
> true)) .add(StructField("key2", StringType, true))
> .add(StructField("val", DoubleType, true))
> 
> 
> schema_df2  = new StructType() .add(StructField("key1", StringType,
> true)) .add(StructField("val", DoubleType, true))
> 
> 
> schema_df3  = new StructType() .add(StructField("key2", StringType,
> true)) .add(StructField("val", DoubleType, true))
> 
> Now if we want to join 
> join1 =  df1.join(df2,"key1") 
> join2 =  df1.join(df3,"key2")
```

I was thinking of bucketing as a solution to speed up the joins. But if I bucket df1 on the key1,then join2  may not benefit, and vice versa (if bucket on key2 for df1).

or Should we bucket df1 twice, one with key1 and another with key2?
Is there a strategy to make both the joins faster for both the joins?

Comment: Star join optimization was added in Spark 2.2, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17626. Are you looking for further improvements?

Comment: @mazaneicha Thanks for your answer. I was not aware of the star join optimization in spark. Will read more about it. If you have any other resource as well, pls paste here.